# Selenium JS switch to previous tab

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, testing

I've recently started writing tests in Selenium javascript and I've had some major confusion regarding switching windows/tabs

For example, this method doesn't seem to work at all after a new tab is opened and switched to, as in, it doesn't switch back to the previous tab (2 tabs open in total) and returns "No other window to switch to":

```
async switchToOtherWindow() {
  const currentHandle = await this.driver.getWindowHandle();
  const windowHandles = await this.driver.getAllWindowHandles();
  for (const handle of windowHandles) {
    if (handle !== currentHandle) {
      await this.driver.switchTo().window(handle);
      return;
    }
  }
  throw new Error('No other window to switch to.');
}
```